# Migrating JSP code to Spring Controller and Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

We are migrating jsp mapping to Spring controller and we want move jsp code to Spring service as we have only scriptlet code in jsp files but the main thing we do not want to change the url that we are calling from UI using ajax call.

Ajax call sample
/ProjectContext/jsp/project/module/downloadFile.jsp

So here .jsp extension will remain same so what should I have to mention in viewResolver.

Please do let me know is there any better way to migrate jsp scriptlet code to spring controller and service.

I have tried below code but not work for me.

```
@Controller
public class DownloadController {
@Autowired
private DownloadService downloadService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/jsp/project/module/downloadFile.jsp", consumes = APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public void downloadFileToLocal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    downloadService.downloadFileToLocal(request, response);
}
}
```

Comment: I found one solution of writing jsp:forward which will redirect to new spring controller but in this case we can not eliminate jsp file. e.g. <jsp:forward page="/project/module/downloadFile"/>

Comment: One more solution, I have created custom Annotation which accept url as argument and on tomcat startup scan for custom Annotation on method in all packages and register url and method in HashMap finally using servlet filter calling method using reflection.with required parameter(implicit jsp object).